# How do i achieve web browsing in flutter without completely opening browser

Tags: android, google-chrome, flutter, uiwebview, android-webview

I want to achieve chrome powered view in android
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmofG.png)

Comment: Please, consider to upload your images in here. The link is temporary and if that one is broken, people will to be able to reach them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) webview. You can check the example in the [github repo](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/url_launcher/url_launcher/example/lib/main.dart)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using [flutter_web_browser](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_web_browser#-readme-tab-) plugin which opens web page inside your flutter app with custom chrome tabs, just like you open a link in chrome browser.

Hope this answers your question.